# Outlook add-in Storage for settings

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I've been trying to use

```
Office.context.roamingSettings.set("keyVal", value)
Office.context.roamingSettings.get("keyVal")
```

To save in storage, but it only work for the current session.
Now I've been trying to the saveAsync. But it doesn't take parameters. So I wanna how it supposed to be used. And also if it keeps the data in all platforms for the user(OWA, mobile, and Desktop)

```
Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function (result) {
        if (result.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
          console.error(`Action failed with message ${result.error.message}`);
        } else {
          console.log(`Settings saved with status: ${result.status}`);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the lifetime of the session you can just use the set and get methods to work with the in-memory copy of the settings property bag.

When you want to persist the settings so that they are available the next time the add-in is used, use the saveAsync method to save the settings after calling the set method. For an example see this code snippet: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/blob/main/samples/outlook/10-roaming-settings/roaming-settings.yaml